# UITableViewController loadView loaded the "xxx-view-xxx" nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I'm trying to create an app with a table with 3 cells

I want to extend the UITableViewController rather than UIViewController, so I come up with this

```
//
//  TodoListTableViewController.swift
//  ListHue
//
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class TodoListTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let items = ["Find Mike", "Buy Eggos", "Kill Demogorgon"]

    //    viewDidLoad
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ToDoItemCell", for: indexPath)

        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

}
```

I kept getting this error when launching my app

`2018-08-01 09:26:53.151150-0400 ListHue[4673:207209] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "r5i-1Z-XpF-view-oGI-0m-9XK" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'`

---

**Identity Tab**
[image]

---

**Connection Tab**

[image]

---

This is a screenshot of my whole thing

[image]

How would one go about debugging this further?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394565/uitableviewcontroller-loadview-loaded-the-mysubscriptionsviewcontroller-ni this might solve your problem

Comment: I did look on that already. I want to extend the `UITableViewController` rather than `UIViewController`.

Comment: Are you extend the UITableViewController in the header too?

Comment: Header, in what file ? - if u don't mind, please tell a bit more details

Comment: Can you github this demo

Comment: did you connected the datasource and delegate

Comment: @Sh_Khan : here you go ? https://github.com/bunlongheng/listhue

Comment: @V_rohit : I have not, but I don't think I need to do that since I extended from the `UITableViewController` rather than `UIViewController`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you dragged a table to a `UIViewController` instance , but you have to drag a `UITableViewController` from the object library ,

The root View for the tableViewController should be a `UITableView` not `UIView` like `UIViewController`

[image]

Comment: and also connect `datasource ` and `delegate ` too ;D

Comment: @V_rohit : I do `NOT` need to do that in my way. XCode take care of that automatically since I entended the right class which is `UITableViewController`

Comment: very sharp eyes ;D

Answer (score 1):

Well, actually the `UITableViewController` expects that its' 'view' property is of type `UITableView`. The easiest way to create one in storyboard is to use corresponding object from the collection (panel in the bottom right corner). In your case seems like you took `UIViewController` from the collection and then just added `UITableView` on it.

So you have two options now:

1. Still the easiest way to fix this is to delete existing one and take `Table view controller` from the collection
2. Also you can delete the root view of the controller, put the table view on its' place and then connect it to the `view` property of your controller. And don't forget to also connect delegate and data source of your table view in this case

Comment: How do I do that ? Can you share steps to do that as part of your answer ?

Comment: But there is no need to connect this in `UITableViewController`

Comment: @Anton, any other suggestion for me ?

Comment: @kyo Updated my answer

Comment: I see, and thank-you for that. Is your comment suggesting me how to fix base on what I have in my senario, or you're trying to tell me the multiple ways of fixing this. I 'm very confuse right now.

Comment: @kyo it contains two ways to fix your issue. I'll divide them in couple of minutes for convenience

Comment: I think your answer looks a bit better now. Thanks for your effort and time.