# How add IBOutlet to class in embedded TableView

Tags: swift, xcode

Please give me a hint how to add IBOUTLET variables to the ViewControllerSettings class. TableViewController is embedded on Container View.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to control drag and drop it inside the `ViewControllerSettings` class's definition.

```
class ViewControllerSettings: UITableViewControntroller {
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    //...
}
```

Note: Make sure the class for the UITableViewController is set to `ViewControllerSettings` in your storyboard.

Comment: 0



Im have a next problem...

Exception NSException * "-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "PhO-Au-gvD-view-DUC-HK-jFo" nib but didn't get a UITableView." 0x0000000281a64900

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394565/uitableviewcontroller-loadview-loaded-the-mysubscriptionsviewcontroller-ni) if you still can't figure it out post another question on SO giving the detail and post the link here, I'll surely try to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

control Drag the table view to the above @IBOutlet

Answer (score 0):

From your screenshot, it seems that you have not assigned the `ViewControllerSettings` for `UITableViewController` inside storyboard.

Inside storyboard, select added `UITableViewController`, got to Identity Inspector and set Class as `ViewControllerSettings`.
[image]

Also do connect outlets **inside** your class in .swift file.