# NSException - nib but didn't get a UITableView

Tags: swift, xcode

Im have problem, in embeded on container TableViewController:

Error:
Exception   NSException *   "-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "PhO-Au-gvD-view-DUC-HK-jFo" nib but didn't get a UITableView." 0x0000000281a64900

[image]

['-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "MySubscriptionsViewController" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394565/uitableviewcontroller-loadview-loaded-the-mysubscriptionsviewcontroller-ni)

I read and I still don't know what to do.

```
class ViewControllerSettings: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        if cell == nil {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        }
    

        return cell!
    }
```

The same error:
Exception   NSException *   "[<AB.ViewControllerSettings 0x104730060> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key staticDataSource."   0x00000002807fda10